# Adding weights to MultiDiGraph edges

Tags: python, networkx

I have a multidigraph in which edges have no weight. I would like to add some weights

```
G=MultiDiGraph():
```

......

```
  for u, v, data in G.edges_iter(data=True):
     G.edge[u][v]['weight'] = None
```

And I get the following for the edges:

```
('08B', '09B', {}),
('08B', '09B', {}),
('08B', '09B', {}),
('08B', '09B', 1),
('03P', '05T', {}),
('03P', '05T', 1)]
```

That is, it adds weights only in one instance. How can I add weight to all edges?

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're having is that you access the attributes of edges using an additional dictionary in multi-graphs. In particular, each edge has a dictionary of *copies*, so you access the attributes for a given edge as follows:

```
G.edge[u][v][replicate][attr] = val
```

So if you wanted to update the attributes for *all* between a pair `(u, v)` of nodes, you could define a function like this:

```
def set_multi_edge_attr(u, v, attr, val):
    for repl in G.edge[u][v].keys():
       G.edge[u][v][repl][attr] = val
```

where `repl` represents the copy of an individual edge. Here's a simple example:

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
>>> G.add_edges_from([(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1)])
>>> G.edges(data=True)
[(0, 1, {}), (0, 1, {}), (0, 1, {})]
>>> set_multi_edge_attr(0, 1, 'weight', 1)
>>> G.edges(data=True)
[(0, 1, {'weight': 1}), (0, 1, {'weight': 1}), (0, 1, {'weight': 1})]
```